# How can I get only text in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get the data returned but instead
My code:

```
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    Name = response.xpath( "//h1//text()" ).get(),
```

But data return of Name is:

```
('Name product',)
```

How can I get only 'Example'?

```
Name product
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the below (a.k.a remove the comma you put after ".get()".

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    Name = response.xpath( "//h1//text()" ).get()
```

Note that the comma can be a useful feature to concisely return multiple values (if you didn't know already)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=get#id1), I see:

> .get() always returns a single result; if there are several matches, content of a first match is returned; if there are no matches, None is returned. .getall() returns a list with all results.

So it should return a string, not a tuple.

In your code, I see a comma at the end of the last line: `.get(),`. This could be converting the string into a tuple.